# How to set a critical rule in Odoo8?

Tags: xml, security, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to set a rule for a specific group created by me (named `group_order_admin`) in the model `res.partner`. Belonging to this group implies to belong also to the group `base.group_sale_salesman` (*See Own Leads*).

I want that the users who belong to that group cannot create, update or unlink supliers, but they will be able to read them (Note: supplier is a `res.partner` record with the `supplier` field set to True).

So I wrote the next rule:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="res_partner_order_admin_suppliers">
    <field name="name">res_partner: order admin cannot create or update suppliers</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('supplier', '=', True)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('my_roles.group_order_admin'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

But this rule is not wotking at all. The users who belong to `group_order_admin` can create, update or remove suppliers.

Can anyone help me? How could I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try by having the value to 'True' for perm_write, perm_create & perm_unlink. By coding above rule, you are specifying that this rule applies only when you try to read the model 'res.partner', not when you create, edit or unlink the record. Also I think you need to have your domain as ['supplier','=', False]